# VMAP Midroll Playback Issue: Seeking Solution for Smooth Transition

Tags: ads, exoplayer, vast, imasdk, ima

I'm encountering an issue with VMAP while playing ads. Specifically, when the video length is shorter than the midroll start time, the player delays transitioning to the next media. Instead, it waits until the midroll start time, plays the midroll slowly, and then proceeds to the next media.

How can I address this problem? I would like the player to move to the next media immediately after the video ends, especially if there is an ad.

I've been trying to figure out a solution, but I haven't had any success yet.